# Laravel ajax "invalid or unexpected token" on .append

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, controller, append

I am trying to call my table contents using ajax append from a laravel controller function. I am getting this error though

[image: 1]

Ajax:

```
    function fetchcategory() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/clinical/bbr-category-configuration-data",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response){
                // console.log(response.all_categories);
                $.each(response.all_categories, function (key, item) {
                    $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
                        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
                        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
                        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\ 
                        </tr>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller: (tabled retrieved form model HmsBbrCategory)

```
public function fetchcategory(){
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::all();
    return response()->json([
        'all_categories'=>$all_categories,
    ]);
}
```

Route:

```
    Route::get('/bbr-category-configuration-data', [BBRCategoryConfigurationController::class,'fetchcategory']);
```

What syntax did I do wrong to get that unexpected token error, at first glance they seem to all encased inside the append. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't pu my finger around it,

But VSCode doesn't like your posted text

I only delete all last character and added them new and voila it works

```
$.each(response.all_categories, function (key, item) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr>\
        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
        <td>'+item.category_name+'</td>\
        </tr>');
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, the code you provided looks virtually identical to the one i have, what did you mean by "delete all last character"?

Comment: @STGSH i deleted al  \ in your code in vs code and added by typing them in again

Comment: i see, ill do this if i get this same issue again, weird error but still thanks for the help!

Comment: You enter another Utf8 character that looks like \ ihave a german widows, with german keybord. with the keybord you should look at

Answer (score 0):

it's just javascript string syntax. you cant escape newline like this.

this version should work.

```
$('tbody').append('<tr>'+
  '<td>'+item.category_name+'</td>'+
  '<td>'+item.category_name+'</td>'+
  '<td>'+item.category_name+'</td>'+
  '<td>'+item.category_name+'</td>'+
'</tr>');
```

or better, with newer syntax.

```
$('tbody').append(`<tr>
  <td>${item.category_name}</td>
  <td>${item.category_name}</td>
  <td>${item.category_name}</td>
  <td>${item.category_name}</td>
</tr>`);
```

Comment: tried these, the console shows the first out gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and the second one `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: i edited my post. can you try again ? first version should work now. and second version may not be supported by your browser.